# Have form's action be a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have a form's action be a javascript file that takes the value of the single input field, in the form, and alerts that value.

So on submit, get value of input field that was submitted with form, alert this value.
Is that possible with javascript / jQuery

Comment: Why would it need to be in the form's action field? Just use JavaScript on the form's submit event.

Comment: It's a shame I need to write more than 3 letters to post a comment; "Yes". However, **what have you tried?**

Comment: concept makes no sense since javascript file can't process post or get

Comment: @j08691 I didn't know a form had a submit event. Thank you, I will look into that.

Comment: @PaulS. Nothing, but that was because I didn't know a form fired a submit event on submission. I thought the only way to process a form's submission was through post or get.

Comment: @charlietfl I thought that too, but apparently a form fires a submit event on submission.

Comment: @IMUXIxD yes form has a `submit` event but server can't process GET or POST for a js file is the point. `action` in form is url at server. `submit` event ocurs in browser

Comment: @charlietfl Ah, okay. I, now, realised that the proper way to do what I was trying to do is not through a js file being a form's action; but, preventing the default action and preforming the alert with normal client side js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said "alert", I'm going to assume you mean client-side JavaScript, in which case the answer is: No. You could set the action to be a JavaScript pseudo-URI, but that wouldn't be sane. Use an event handler instead.

Start out by having an `action` pointing to a server side handler for the form. (Follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)).

Then:

1. Bind an event handler to the form's submit event
2. Do what you want with the data
3. Cancel the normal behaviour of the form

Such:

```
<form action="...">
  <label> foo <input name="foo"> </label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    alert(event.target.elements.foo.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did mean client-side JS. I also learned a lot from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($('#inputtxtID').val());
  return false;
});
```